# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined"

Tags: linux, .net-core, azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps to publish a .NET 6 application to Linux app service:

#Publish it to the Azure App Service

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    azureSubscription: $(azureSPNName)
    appName: $(azureAppServiceName)
    package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
    runtimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    startUpCommand: 'dotnet {Project}.dll'
```

Job log shows successful deployment, but then receives the error:

```
...
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
...
```

It does look like new changes are applied and available in the application, but I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Anyone have a solution for this?

[Configuration Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzYPs.png)

This does not work either, same error in the same part of the log:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    azureSubscription: $(azureSPNName)
    appName: $(azureAppServiceName)
    package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone else had the same issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azurewebapp-typeerror-cannot-read-property-updates/1608178

I was using an Azure Resource Manager that was using publish profile based authentication.  After I switched it to a service connection to an Azure Resource Manager that uses service principal authentication it is working.

Comment: Glad to know it's working with a service principal ARM service connection! Could you please mark it as answer so that it could help others who has same issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from below parameters from your deploy task which only applied to `linux` app:

```
    runtimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    startUpCommand: 'dotnet {Project}.dll'
```

They are optional, you can `remove` them, and try again the pipeline for a check.

When you `add` these parameters, it will try to update the App Service Configuration settings:

[image]

Your app service should have configuration settings got updated as below screenshot. When you create the app service,please make sure you have created correct app service type.
[image]

In addition, you can check "[Azure Functions runtime versions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#languages)" for the runtime version on your app.

Comment: My configuration settings look the similar.  Removing these option parameters did not have any effect. Still receiving the same error after successful deployment.